# helm escape ` in template yaml file

Tags: kubernetes-helm, go-templates

Does anyone know how to espace ` in helm template?

I try to add \ in front doesn't seem to work

original:

```
{{- if not .Values.istio_cni.chained }}
            k8s.v1.cni.cncf.io/networks: '{{ appendMultusNetwork (index .ObjectMeta.Annotations `k8s.v1.cni.cncf.io/networks`) `istio-cni` }}',
            {{- end }}
```

Tried:

```
  {{- if not .Values.istio_cni.chained }}
            k8s.v1.cni.cncf.io/networks: '{{`{{ appendMultusNetwork (index .ObjectMeta.Annotations \`k8s.v1.cni.cncf.io/networks\`) `istio-cni` }}`}}',
            {{- end }}
```

Error:

```
Error: parse error at (test/templates/istio-sidecar-injector-istio-system-ConfigMap.yaml:29): unexpected "k8s" in operand
```

Answer (score 0):

In the [Go text/template language](https://pkg.go.dev/text/template) backticks delimit "raw string constants"; in standard Go, [there is no escaping at all inside raw string literals](https://go.dev/ref/spec#String_literals) and they cannot contain backticks.

In your example, it looks like you're trying to emit a Go template block into the output.  You can make this work if you use double quotes around the variable names inside the template, and then backticks around the whole thing:

```yaml
#                                    double quotes around string literal
#                                                           v         v
k8s.v1.cni.cncf.io/networks: '{{`{{ appendMultusNetwork ... "istio-cni" }}`}}'
#                               ^                                         ^
#                                    backticks around whole expression
```

Comment: It works if I do this:     k8s.v1.cni.cncf.io/networks: '{{\`{{ appendMultusNetwork (index .ObjectMeta.Annotations "k8s.v1.cni.cncf.io/networks") "istio-cni" }}\`}}',

Comment: You're right, I needed one more set of braces than I originally had in this answer.  (So it is a template expression that expands to a string, that happens to be a template expression.)  I apologize for the confusion.

Comment: Yea. But it’s very helpful for you to point out using double quotes to replace the backticks. It all work out :)